# Probability of future event only given mean

Tags: probability

"In 2013, the mean number of Google searches per day was 2.922E9. On a ramdomly selected day in 2013, what is the probability that there were more than 2.95E9 Google searches?"

I can't find a way of approaching this that only involves using the single mean that was provided. I thought the Poisson distribution may work but it would require doing 2.95E9! (factorial) and that's just not feasible for me to calculate.

What method is best suited to approach this problem? Thanks for the help!

Comment: This should be impossible if one is not given the type of distribution.

Answer (score 0):

For large $\lambda$, $Poisson(\lambda) \approx Normal(\mu = \lambda, \sigma^2 =  \lambda)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've applied this approach to the problem and started to solve for Z score, since I'm assuming it to be a normal distribution. I now have a small problem that the Z score is 518. I'm much more used to Z scores being around -3 to 3... There are two follow up questions that are very similar to the original question that would all yield 0 probability with the current approach, which makes me think I've made a mistake somewhere. Is there another approach other than the poisson distribution that may provide better results?

Comment: Yes this should bring the answer 0. I don't see a good way to approach this question differently. To be honest, the Poisson model is a fairly poor practical model for this situation, as not all days are equal. Some overdispersed distribution (like Negative Binomial) should be more realistic, but you don't have enough data to fit it.